# In ZSH, variable behavior is different than in bash

Tags: bash, zsh

Sorry for the terrible title, but I don't really know how to describe this.

I used to have this bash script (echo in place of actual functionality for brevity):

```
branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | sed 's|refs/heads/||')
for branch in $branches; do
  echo $branch
done
```

and the for-loop would parse each branch one-by-one.

Upon switching to ZSH (or perhaps it was updating git 2.28, but I didn't see anything in patch notes), this no longer works. The variable "branches" is now one string, so the for-loop iterates once, processing `$branch` as just the output of `$branches`

Now, I got around it by doing the following:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | sed 's|refs/heads/||'); do
  echo $branch
done
```

and now the script works like it did before.

Does anyone have a good explanation why? I'm having trouble describing the keywords for this particular change. I will admit I am quite new to ZSH, and am very used to bash.

Comment: Still, both methods `for i in $` `for i in $(...)` are antipatterns. I would advise to better to do a while read loop. [bashfaq how to read a stream line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and not depend on word splitting.

Comment: Seems like zsh does not like your assignment, perhaps (?). Try to wrap your assignment (i.e. ```branches="$(git...)"``` in double quotes. I'm actually surprised that in Bash command substitution ($(...)) does not require double quotes when assigning to a variable. Using double-quotes in this case is probably good practice though.